# Probability, expected value

Tags: probability

I was reading about risk aversion and there was a bet, if you take it there's a $1/2300$ chance of not loosing any money. Why is the chance, $1/2300$? Why is the expected value $5,000$ dollar?

The Bet - Flip a coin, if you guess correctly, you gain $200$ dollar and loose $100$ dollar. So, if you flip the coin $100$ times, the chance of not loosing any money is $1/2300$ and the expected value is $5,000$ dollar.

Link to the article -http://ww.andreisimonov.com/Microstr_PhD/RiskAversion_JEP2001.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The probability you end up with less than you started with is the probability you lose the bet more than twice the number of times that you win. E.g. Win 30 times, lose 70 times you are in the hole. Win 35 times, lose 65 times you're in the green.

Let $X$ be the number of times you win. Then $Y=100-X$ is the number of times you lose.

$$P(2x < y) = P(x < 100/3) = P(x \le 33)$$

This is binomial, so

$$P(x \le 33)= \sum_{x=0}^{33} {100\choose x} 0.5^{100} = \dfrac{553785737846639752356280235}{1267650600228229401496703205376}$$

And

$$\left|\dfrac{1}{2300} - \dfrac{553785737846639752356280235}{1267650600228229401496703205376}\right| \approx 0.000002$$
so it appears the author made an estimation.

As for the expected value, you would expect to win 50 times because the probability of winning a single toss is $0.5$, and these bing independent trials, $E(X)=0.5(100)=50$.

The amount of money you wind up with is  $M=200X-100Y$. Thus

$$E(M)=E(200X-100Y) = 200E(X)-100E(Y) = 200(50)-100(50) = 5000$$